# After ,While Converting DataTable to PDF , the PDF files is not able to open

Tags: c#, pdf

BY using the Following code the data table is converting , it is file with more than 50000 rows of Data. IF there is any error in the Code or something else need to added.

```
private static void ConvertDataTableToPdf(DataTable dataTable, string pdfFilePath)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pdfFilePath))
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            sw.Write($"{column.ColumnName}\t");
        }
        sw.WriteLine();

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                sw.Write($"{item}\t");
            }
            sw.WriteLine();
        }
    }

}
```

and while open the PDF file it showing error

> "We Cannot able to open the file "
> something went wrong

Comment: PDFs aren't plain-text files. You seem to be writing tab-separated fields into the file – that's a [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) file.